# What does "Version" mean when viewing reference properties in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, assembly-references, valuetuple

I am currently battling "DLL hell" in Visual Studio 2017. For unknown reasons, I suddenly got a problem with System.ValueTuple, where the error I get is the classic problem that have been asked many times before:

> Could not load file or assembly 'System.ValueTuple, Version=4.0.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

I cannot really figure it out, as I don't think I should have any reference to 4.0.2.0. VS tells me the following:

[image]

What I don't get is how the "Version" of the System.ValueTuple says 4.0.2.0, when I have installed version 4.4.0 according to the path of the DLL and according to NuGet Manager.

So, why is it like this?

Comment: You have installed the version 4.4.0 of the NuGet package that doesn't necessarily contain an assembly with version 4.4.0.0.

Comment: Ehm, that sounds completely weird =) So, When I install verion 4.4.0, I am really installing version 4.0.2.0 then, in the case of System.ValueTuple. Then I dont get, what is a package version and why does it differ from the assembly verson, that I am actually installing?

Comment: That's a question for the producer of the package. Many libraries fix the assembly version to something like 4.0.0.0.

Comment: So, 4.40 means very little in this case, and NuGet versions are in most cases then completely off; the actual version of the library can be anything else? I see this discrepancy with a lot (most?) things I install from NuGet etc.